# IntelliJ isn't running. and show no error message

Tags: intellij-idea

[idea.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEvuT.png)

IntelliJ isn't opening. When I run idea.bat from cmd, it shows like from the picture. what can I do??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you please share vmoptions file: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties ?

Answer (score 1):

Caused by the fact you are using ja-netfilter.jar library that is in fact crack for the IDE.
Remove the mention of this file from IDE's VM options.